# Mac/Windows Installer - Run on Startup

Tags: installation

I realize there are 10,000 answers for this on StackOverflow, but my needs are quite specific:
i) install a JAR file on
ii) Windows/Mac
so that it
iii) runs on Startup
oh and
iv) auto-JRE install would be great

That's it. I've looked at several tools including Inno Setup:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php#features

but there does not seem to be a good tool that targets *both* Windows and Mac.

Any ideas?

Thank you
Misha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) a try.  Free, open source, and the 1.3 snapshots show support for Mac OS X, though it's not quite complete yet.  You might also try BitRock InstallBuilder if you need full OS X support immediately.  Probably a bit cheaper than InstallAnywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Flexera's InstallAnywhere is a cross-platform installer supporting Windows, Linux, and Macintosh:
http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm

(note: it's expensive)